# IE Conditional statement not loading

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I am experiencing a problem when trying to load a style sheet specifically for IE. I have a css file for IE7 and one for IE8. Now the browser on my desktop is IE8 and I am using developer tools to switch between IE7 and IE8. In developer, I can see that the conditionals are not being recognised because if I make an amendment in one of the the css files, no changes take place even after cache removal. Is there something simple I am missing here?

I have also tried before all other css files and after and included an X-UA line.Hope someone can help. Thanks

```
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

      <!--[if IE 7]>

      <link href="/domain/users/css/jmenu/css/ie7_jmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <link href="/domain/users/css/ie7_css_forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <link href="/domain/users/css/ie7_colmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <p style="color: blue; font-size:18px;">You are using IE7</p>

      <![endif]-->

      <!--[if IE 8]>

      <link href="/domain/users/css/jmenu/css/ie8_jmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <link href="/domain/users/css/ie8_css_forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <link href="/domain/users/css/ie8_colmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
      <p style="color: blue; font-size:18px;">You are using IE8</p>

      <![endif]-->
```

Comment: where are you calling your default stylesheet?

Comment: I have a header.php file which contains a menu and I am calling from there.

Comment: is it being called after the ie stylesheets?

Comment: If you are running IE version 8 "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />" won't be doing any good because IE8 won't know about IE9, it being a later version. Also does taking out the p tags help?

Comment: @anurupr The conditionals are in the header. So they are being called when header.php loads. Thanks

Comment: @Ben Removed the <p> tags, but still the same. Thanks

Comment: Did you remove the IE9 meta tag also? Have you tried taking the tags outside the conditional comments to make sure they are working? Also make sure IE hasn't auto updated to IE11 as its developer tools are broken

Comment: i'm just trying to understand the order in which your stylesheets are being called . i cannot see the default stylesheet in your code. so if you could let us know where the default stylesheets are being called in your code. i think that should give a good idea on how your stylesheets are being called